# Como gerar a minha BaseURL (link) do PostgreSQL que esta no Heroku para integrar ao meu front-end Angular?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, front-end, angular, heroku

Minha dúvida é: como eu gero o *link* (baseurl) para que meu *front-end* acesse os dados vindo dessa base (PostgreSQL) que esta hospedada no **Heroku**?

Meu PostgreSQL lá do Heroku libera essas informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a img acima eu tenho **host**, **database** e etc., agora eu preciso colocar alguma informação dessas aqui nessa parte de meu código *front-end* (Service – Serviço) `eventosUrl = '???';` para liberar os dados vindo do bd Heroku:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class EventoService {

//eventosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/eventos';
eventosUrl = '???';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

listar() {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.eventosUrl);
  }
}
```

Não sei se eu preciso colocar algo no meu arquivo **application.properties** já que eu localmente coloquei isso para liberar o acesso a base de dados via Ajax (requisições):

**ARQUIVO application.properties:**

```
origem-permitida=http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: Teu frontend não deveria acessar o banco de dados. Se teu front souber acessar o banco de dados, qualquer usuário poderá pegar esta informação pelo browser e invadir teu banco de dados.

Comment: Olha é o que eu aprendi, porém eu consigo fazer essa integração através do `localhost`, conforme o código acima. Não sei como tem esse informação da qual tu te referes e sim um *link*, ou seja, a baseURL. Essa camada é de serviço e não é diretamente na *viwer* **HTML** quem trata isso é o *framework* **Angular**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cria um arquivo de configuração com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
export const API_CONFIG = {
     baseUrl: "https://nome-do-app.herokuapp.com",
}
```

Em cada service vc importa esse arquivo e nos métodos que se comunicam com a api vc coloca dessa maneira:

```
return this.http.get<Objeto[]>(`${API_CONFIG.baseUrl}/nome-da-rota`);
```

Dessa forma, se algum dia vc mudar de https://nome-do-app.herokuapp.com para https://nome-do-app2.herokuapp.com, você altera somente no arquivo de configuração e não é preciso mexer em nhm service.

Comment: Perfeito, consegui fazendo dessa maneira!